# Client/Server Programming using Sockets

Tags: java, sockets

Recently I have received an assignment where I had to build a distributed application of a Billing Service which involves one client and one server. I have already made the full program on NetBeans IDE 7.2.1. The codes of client and server are given below.

Server Side:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class OBS_Server_11398 implements Runnable {
    Socket OBS_Socket = null;
    public Hashtable < String, BigDecimal > OBS_Billing_Table;
    public Hashtable < String, String > Password_Table;

    public OBS_Server_11398(Socket OBS_Socket, Hashtable < String, BigDecimal > OBS_Billing_Table,
        Hashtable < String, String > Password_Table) {
        this.OBS_Socket = OBS_Socket;
        this.OBS_Billing_Table = OBS_Billing_Table;
        this.Password_Table = Password_Table;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Connected to Client...");
        // connection between server and client
        PrintWriter pwd = null;
        boolean chFlag = true;
        try {
            int ans = 0;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(OBS_Socket.getInputStream());
            pwd = new PrintWriter(OBS_Socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            String OBS_Password = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Account Password :" + OBS_Password);
            // The Account is obtained from the table
            boolean Password_Exists = Password_Table.containsKey(OBS_Password);

            if (Password_Exists) {
                pwd.println("Successful");
            } else {
                pwd.println("Failed");
            }
            do {
                BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal(0);
                String passwd = null;
                String OBS_Account = Password_Table.get(OBS_Password);
                BigDecimal balance = (BigDecimal) OBS_Billing_Table.get(OBS_Account);
                Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(OBS_Socket.getInputStream());

                Date now;
                now = new Date();
                DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG);
                String Current_Date = df.format(now);

                String chSplit = sc1.nextLine();
                int Option = 0;

                if (chSplit.indexOf("-") != -1) {
                    String[] choiceObs = chSplit.split("-");

                    Option = Integer.parseInt(choiceObs[0]);
                    System.out.println("Enter your Option: " + Option);
                    System.out.println(choiceObs[1]);
                    if (Option == 4 || Option == 5) {
                        passwd = choiceObs[1];
                    } else {
                        amount = new BigDecimal(choiceObs[1]);
                    }
                }

                PrintWriter pw1 = new PrintWriter(OBS_Socket.getOutputStream(), true);

                switch (Option) {
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("\n * * * * VIEW BILL * * * * ");
                        // of OBS_Account
                        pw1.println("Your Current bill as of " + Current_Date + " is: OMR " + balance.setScale(3, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));

                        break;

                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("\n * * * * PAY BILL * * * * ");
                        pw1.println(balance.setScale(3, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
                        OBS_Billing_Table.put(OBS_Account, new BigDecimal(sc1.nextLine()));
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("\n * * * * CHECK BALANCE * * * * ");
                        pw1.println("Your Balance Amount as of " + Current_Date + " is: OMR " + balance.setScale(3, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));

                        break;

                    case 4:
                        System.out.println("** Change Password **");

                        Password_Table.put(passwd, OBS_Account);
                        Password_Table.remove(OBS_Password);
                        OBS_Password = passwd;
                        pw1.println("Your OBS_Account password is successfully changed!");
                        break;

                    case 5:
                        chFlag = false;
                        pw1.println("Exit Successfully..");
                        break;

                    default:
                        // choice Flag = true;

                        System.out.println("****************************************");
                        System.out.println("** Wrong Choice! Please try again! **");
                        System.out.println("****************************************");

                }
            } while (chFlag);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Waiting for Client to Connect......");
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(5555);
        Socket OBS_Socket = null;
        Hashtable < String, String > Password_Table = new Hashtable < String, String > ();
        Hashtable < String, BigDecimal > OBS_Billing_Table = new Hashtable < String, BigDecimal > ();
        Password_Table.put("1234", "AA1234");
        Password_Table.put("5678", "BB5678");
        OBS_Billing_Table.put("AA1234", new BigDecimal(5000));
        OBS_Billing_Table.put("BB5678", new BigDecimal(2500));
        while (true) {
            OBS_Socket = ss.accept();
            OBS_Server_11398 ast = new OBS_Server_11398(OBS_Socket, OBS_Billing_Table,
                Password_Table);
            Thread t = new Thread(ast);
            t.start();
        }

    }
}
```

Client Side:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

public class OBS_Client_11398 {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Socket OBS_Socket;
        boolean acFlag = false;
        boolean pwdFlag = false;
        String strpasswd = null;
        int passwd = 0;

        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        PrintWriter pwd = null;
        Scanner sc = null;
        String res = null;

        do {
            acFlag = false;
            do {
                pwdFlag = false;
                try {
                    System.out.println(" * * * * OMANTEL BILLING SERVICE * * * * ");
                    System.out.println("\nPlease enter your OBS Account Number : ");
                    strpasswd = scn.nextLine();
                    passwd = Integer.parseInt(strpasswd);
                    if (strpasswd.length() != 4) {
                        // System.out.println(strpin.length());
                        pwdFlag = true;
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("Error! Please Enter a Password with 4 Digits Only..");
                    pwdFlag = true;
                }
            } while (pwdFlag);

            OBS_Socket = new Socket("localhost", 5555);
            pwd = new PrintWriter(OBS_Socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            pwd.println(strpasswd);
            sc = new Scanner(OBS_Socket.getInputStream());

            res = sc.next();
            if (res.equals("Failed")) {
                System.out.println("ERROR! You have Entered an Invalid Account Number");
                acFlag = true;
            }
        } while (acFlag);
        if (res.equals("Successful")) {
            boolean chFlag = false;
            do {
                chFlag = false;
                System.out.println("\n *      - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -       *");
                System.out.println(" *                                              *");
                System.out.println(" *    WELCOME TO OMANTEL BILLING SERVICE        *");
                System.out.println(" *      Programmed by: Sania Macci - 11398      *");
                System.out.println(" *                                              *");
                System.out.println(" *    Choose an Option from the list below      *");
                System.out.println(" *             --> 1 <-- View Bill              *");
                System.out.println(" *             --> 2 <-- Pay Bill               *");
                System.out.println(" *             --> 3 <-- Check Balance          *");
                System.out.println(" *             --> 4 <-- Change Password        *");
                System.out.println(" *             --> 5 <-- Exit                   *");
                System.out.println(" *                                              *");
                System.out.println(" *      - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -       *");
                System.out.print("\nSelected Option : ");

                Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
                int ch = 0;
                try {
                    Scanner scCH = new Scanner(OBS_Socket.getInputStream());
                    PrintWriter pw1 = new PrintWriter(OBS_Socket.getOutputStream(),
                        true);
                    ch = sc1.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(ch);

                    if (ch == 1) {
                        scCH = new Scanner(OBS_Socket.getInputStream());
                        pw1.println(ch + "-" + "0");
                        System.out.println("");
                        System.out.println(" * * * * VIEW BILL * * * * ");
                        System.out.println("This bill will be Updated after every Transaction");
                        System.out.println("");
                        System.out.print(scCH.nextLine());
                    } else if (ch == 2) {
                        scCH = new Scanner(OBS_Socket.getInputStream());
                        pw1.println(ch + "-" + "2");
                        System.out.println("");
                        System.out.println(" * * * * PAY BILL * * * * ");
                        BigDecimal totalBill = new BigDecimal(scCH.nextLine());
                        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                        System.out.println("Enter Amount to Pay: ");
                        BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal(scanner.nextLine());
                        totalBill = totalBill.subtract(amount, new MathContext(5));
                        pw1.println(totalBill);
                    } else if (ch == 3) {
                        pw1.println(ch + "-" + "3");
                        System.out.println("");
                        System.out.println(" * * * * CHECK BALANCE * * * * ");
                        scCH = new Scanner(OBS_Socket.getInputStream());
                        System.out.print(scCH.nextLine());
                    } else if (ch == 4) {
                        scCH = new Scanner(OBS_Socket.getInputStream());
                        System.out.print("Please Enter a New Password: ");
                        int pinNum = sc1.nextInt();
                        pw1.println(ch + "-" + pinNum);
                        System.out.print(scCH.nextLine());

                    } else if (ch == 5) {
                        pw1.println(ch + "-" + "0");
                        scCH = new Scanner(OBS_Socket.getInputStream());
                        System.out.print(scCH.nextLine());
                        System.exit(-1);
                    } else {
                        System.out.print("WRONG CHOICE!! Please try again...\n");
                        chFlag = true;
                    }

                    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String readString = scanner.nextLine();
                    if (readString.equals("")) {
                        chFlag = true;
                    }
                } catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
                    System.out.println("Wrong Choice! Please try again\n");
                    chFlag = true;
                } catch (Exception e) { // e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } while (chFlag);

        }
    }
}
```

The problem in this code is that, when I change the password and login with the new one, it doesn't accept it and uses the old one. The same problem is with the pay bill and view bill functions; the amount of bill is not changing the second time I run the program even when I 'pay' the bill.

When I showed my program to my teacher, she said to add 2 more features. So I want your opinion of what other 2 features or functionalities can be added in the program. Any help in getting the code started would be a great!

Comment: Try `flush()`ing the `OBS_Socket` after writing to it. This may happen that your data is not delivered to server and remains in buffer.

Comment: @Tariq You can't flush a socket, and he is using auto-flush mode on his `PrintWriter.`

Comment: The client never closes its socket and keeps creati new ones. The server keeps creating new streams on the same socket.

Comment: ahan
so what do you suggest i should do to make it work?